# How to get image url from gcp storage to data studio table report

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iot

I want that in my data studio report I can add the link of images uploaded from my device to google cloud storage bucket.

I know how to manually achieve the goal, I need to know that when my data is loaded from bigquery to data studio in realtime; so how can I also fetch the image url dynamically.

Comment: Can you provide more details about your use case and what you managed to figure out by yourself ?

Comment: I uploaded some images to storage bucket using python. I  made my storage bucket public so i got url for each of my image. Now, i need to know how can i dynamically get the url to my data studio report every time a new image is uploaded. @W_B